# how can i tap on wheel picker to enter time in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using wheel picker style for time in Swift UI

```
    HStack {
        Text(title)
        Spacer()
        Text("\(formatter.string(from: date))")
            .onTapGesture {
                showPicker.toggle()
            }
            .padding(8)
            .background(bg1Color)
            .foregroundColor(showPicker ? fgColor : Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(8)
    }
    if showPicker {
         DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: displayedComponents)
            .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            .accentColor(fgColor)
    }
```

But with this I can't tap and enter time using keyboard  like below screen shot in calender[image]..

please let me know if there a way to achieve this behavior..Thanks in advance .

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried to get this to work?

Comment: It’s a custom functionality which you need to program. I think as shown in your screenshot, it’s a mixture of a textfield and datepicker.

Comment: updated my question with the code I have

Comment: use `DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])`. This will let you "....tap on wheel picker to enter time in swiftui".

Comment: is there any way to disable that